# Spring JavaConfig - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type

Tags: java, spring

I would like to test the Spring `@Configuration` with a small test case, but it throws error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.mycompany.MavenVaadinSpring.service.UserManager] is defined:

What have I done wrong? My code is below:

`AppConfigTest.java`:

```
public class AppConfigTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaConfigApplicationContext context = new JavaConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        UserManager userManager = context.getBean(UserManager.class);
    }
}
```

`AppConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@ResourceBundles("classpath:jdbc-mysql")
public abstract class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();        
        return basicDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDao userDao() {
        UserDao UDI = new UserDaoImpl();
        UDI.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return UDI;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserManager userManager() {
        UserManager UM = new UserManagerImpl();
        UM.setUserDao(userDao());

        return UM;
    }

    abstract @ExternalValue("jdbc.url") String url();
    abstract @ExternalValue("jdbc.username") String username();
    abstract @ExternalValue("jdbc.password") String password();
    abstract @ExternalValue("jdbc.jdbc.driverClassName") String classname();    
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main"   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type   [com.mycompany.MavenVaadinSpring.service.UserManager] is defined: 
at org.springframework.config.java.context.TypeSafeBeanFactoryUtils.getBean(TypeSafeBeanFactoryUtils.java:46)
at org.springframework.config.java.context.JavaConfigApplicationContext.getBean(JavaConfigApplicationContext.java:378)
at com.mycompany.MavenVaadinSpring.AppConfigTest.main(AppConfigTest.java:11)
```

Comment: Balus thanks for improving the outlook of my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using the standalone spring-javaconfig project here (as evidenced by the .config.java packaging and use of the JavaConfigApplicationContext class).  This project is no longer supported since its inclusion in Spring 3.0.  The packaging has changed, and JavaConfigApplicationContext is now called AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.  The overall programming model, however, is the same.

Give this same scenario a shot against a release of Spring 3 and see if you get the same results.  If you need a GA release, Spring 3.0.6 is now available; if you can deal with milestones, try Spring 3.1 M2, or even a nightly snapshot of Spring 3.1.  You'll find Java configuration support has been significantly enhanced in these later versions.

Comment: Hello Chris, What did I miss in your post ? http://blog.springsource.com/2008/03/26/spring-java-configuration-whats-new-in-m3/ There is a line "AnnotationApplicationContext deprecated" and some word about collosion with "Spring 2.5's Annotation-Driven Injection" and you use "JavaConfigApplicationContext" in your examples. But I will follow your words and thank for you quick reply

Comment: Ups post I mentioned dated to 2008

Comment: Where can I find up to date explanation about how to ?

Comment: Ok, I got it http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java

Comment: AppConfig is abstract.   Is there a concrete version?

Comment: Yes, based on the following explanation http://blog.springsource.com/2008/03/26/spring-java-configuration-whats-new-in-m3/ but it is too old form of using JavaConfig dated 2008. The up to date usage can be found here : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java