# Where is JavaConfigApplicationContext class nowadays?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-java-config

What is JavaConfigApplicationContext class address in maven artifacts?

Can't find it in neither of

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Spring 4.2.0, in order to create an instance of `ApplicationContext` from `@Configuration`-annotated class use:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295738/2267100) for reasons why `JavaConfigApplicationContext` does not exist anymore.